# Access pointer value of a struct inside a function

Tags: go, reflection

I want to pass a struct object to a function & be able to access its pointer value from that function. I am not able to understand why the following is resulting in error.

```
func GetStructFieldPointers(u interface{}, jsonFields []string) []interface{} {
    structVal := reflect.ValueOf(&u).Elem()
    structType := reflect.TypeOf(u)
    numberOfFields := structVal.NumField() // getting error here reflect:
                                           // call of reflect.Value.NumField
                                           // on interface Value
    numberOfJSONFields := len(jsonFields)
    res := make([]interface{}, numberOfJSONFields)
    fmt.Println(jsonFields)
    for fieldIndex, field := range jsonFields {
        for i := 0; i < numberOfFields; i++ {
            if structType.Field(i).Tag.Get("json") == field {
                valueField := structVal.Field(i)
                res[fieldIndex] = valueField.Addr().Interface()
            }
        }
    }

    return res
}

type User struct {
    Id             int      `json:"id"`
    Name           string   `json:"name"`
    Address        string   `json:"address"`
}
user := User{}
res := GetStructFieldPointers(user, []string{"id", "name"})
```

To make this work, I had to make `structType` as a parameter like following:

```
func GetStructFieldPointers(u interface{}, structType reflect.Type, jsonFields []string) []interface{} {
    structVal := reflect.ValueOf(u).Elem()
    // structType := reflect.TypeOf(u)
    numberOfFields := structVal.NumField() 
    numberOfJSONFields := len(jsonFields)
    res := make([]interface{}, numberOfJSONFields)
    fmt.Println(jsonFields)
    for fieldIndex, field := range jsonFields {
        for i := 0; i < numberOfFields; i++ {
            if structType.Field(i).Tag.Get("json") == field {
                valueField := structVal.Field(i)
                res[fieldIndex] = valueField.Addr().Interface()
            }
        }
    }

    return res
}

user := User{}
res := GetStructFieldPointers(&user, reflect.TypeOf(user), []string{"id", "name"})
```

I like to know how to pass `User{}` as a parameter & use in both reflect.ValueOf & reflect.TypeOf calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On this line: `structVal := reflect.ValueOf(&u).Elem()` you're taking the address of an interface (the argument of your func) and not an address to the interface's underlying value, and then you're passing the pointer to `ValueOf`, so the `.Elem()` call returns the "elem value" to which the pointer points to, which is the `interface`, not struct.

If you know for a fact that the passed in value is a struct and not a pointer, all you need is this: `structVal := reflect.ValueOf(u)`.

If a pointer was passed to your func, eg `GetStructFieldPointers(&u, ...` then this is what you want: `structVal := reflect.ValueOf(u).Elem()`.

But also you can handle both cases by checking the value's kind.

```
rv := reflect.ValueOf(u)
if rv.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
    rv = rv.Elem()
}
if rv.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
    fmt.Println(rv.NumField())
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/9F9LNnwEaH

**Update**:
Took a better look at your code... If you want to be able to get the addresses of your struct's fields, you need to pass a pointer to the struct as the argument, or else those fields are going to be unaddressable.

https://play.golang.org/p/RaA2rau3s-

Comment: Thanks for the answer.